# How to gather facts about disks using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to write an Ansible playbook which will identify newly added disks on a RHEL machine.  The plan is to run the playbook and cache the disks at that point in time as a fact prior to creating the new disks.  After creating the new disks, the the same playbook would be run again and would compute the difference in disks before and after the disks are created.

For example, `lsblk` initially returns the following:

```
NAME              SIZE  TYPE
sda               100G  disk
├─sda1              1G  part
└─sda2             99G  part
  ├─rhel-root      50G  lvm
  ├─rhel-swap     7.9G  lvm
  └─rhel-home    41.1G  lvm
sr0              1024M  rom
```

after adding 8 new disks, `lsblk` returns:

```
NAME              SIZE  TYPE
sda               100G  disk
├─sda1              1G  part
└─sda2             99G  part
  ├─rhel-root      50G  lvm
  ├─rhel-swap     7.9G  lvm
  └─rhel-home    41.1G  lvm
sdb              18.6G  disk
sdc              18.6G  disk
sdd              18.6G  disk
sde              18.6G  disk
sdf              18.6G  disk
sdg              18.6G  disk
sdh              18.6G  disk
sdi              18.6G  disk
sr0              1024M  rom
```

Ideally I would be able to gather an initial list of disks of the form:

```
['sda']
```

and after creating the disks gather another list of disks of the form:

```
['sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd', 'sde', 'sdf', 'sdg', 'sdh', 'sdi']
```

Computing the difference between the two lists would yield:

```
['sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd', 'sde', 'sdf', 'sdg', 'sdh', 'sdi']
```

which are the 8 newly created disks.

I am trying to avoid using a `shell` or `command` module call if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This information is automatically gathered via Ansible's [fact gathering](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html) mechanism. See [Variables discovered from systems: Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts).

For example:

```yaml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- name: Lets look at some disks
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name: Output disk information
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices
```

If we instead use the `gather_subset` configuration on the [`setup` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/setup_module.html) instead we can speed up the fact gathering and only gather information about system `hardware`.

We can then combine this with the [Python `keys()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys) and the [Jinja2 `list` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.list) to produce your desired output.

```yaml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- name: Lets look at some disks
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Collect only facts about hardware
    setup:
      gather_subset:
      - hardware

  - name: Output disks
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | list
```

It is also possible to configure which facts to gather in the Ansible configuration file [`ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) using the `gather_subset` key in the `[defaults]` section.

If you want to filter out various disk types the easiest way would be to  use `map('regex_search', '*search string*')` to extract the values you want. You can the remove the nulls via `select('string')`.

For example with disks of the form `sd*`:

```yaml
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- name: Lets look at some disks
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Collect only facts about hardware
    setup:
      gather_subset:
      - hardware

  - name: Output disks
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'sd.*') | select('string') | list
```

Comment: After implementing the solution @Nick suggested, I'm seeing the following output:
`
[
      "dm-10",
      "dm-8",
      "fd0",
      "sr0",
      "sda",
      "sdb",
      "dm-9",
      "dm-6",
      "dm-7",
      "dm-4",
      "dm-5",
      "dm-2",
      "dm-3",
      "dm-0",
      "dm-1"
]
`

Running `lsblk` on my machine I do not see any of the device mapper names (dm-#) as listed above and I can correctly see the newly added disks of the form `sdc, sdd, ...`.  Am I wrong to expect to be able to see disk names of the form `sdc, sdd...` from `ansible_devices.keys()`

Comment: Are you looking to list just raw disks? just disk partitions? just logical volumes? The information contained in ansible_devices  is going to be all of the above and you'll have to filter out what you don't want to see. The lsblk command automatically formats this information visually. dm-X entries are generally device mapper entries for logical volumes.

Comment: I'm looking just for raw disks.  I looked through the entire output from `ansible_devices` and didn't seem to see any of the newly created disk names.  I also tried running `lsblk` using `command` in ansible and wasn't able to see the new disks after creation which makes me think the issue may not be with `ansible_disks`.

Comment: The original answer from @Nick works perfectly - I realized I had a stray `connection: local' that I hadn't noticed so I was collecting facts about the wrong machine.

Comment: This info is very valuable. What if want to use on systems that have hd, sd, nvme, xd drives? How do I make this generic to collect these device names?

Answer (score -2):

Try this command after any disk adding you can see the changes:

```
for d in /sys/class/scsi_device/* ; do echo 1 > $d/device/rescan; done
```

Answer (score -2):

```
- name: Check disk size
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_devices[item].size }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_devices.keys()|list }}"
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer.